# Excel VBA and Connected Experiences Issues

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

We created a relatively large Excel VBA based system used by hundreds of users across the US.  It creates a number of reports as well as fairly complicated line drawings including 3D views.  The system has been running fine for many years but encountered an error of 2010 resulting in an Automation Error that appears related to a Nov 14th Microsoft update.  The error has been experienced in 32 bit and 64 bit Excel 365.  After the automation error occurs, the entire Excel application shuts down.  We discovered that disconnecting from the internet allowed the system to run normally.  In addition, the user can stay connected to the internet but the system will only run when turning off Connected Experiences.  Downloading the latest update didn't help.  When the system processes the reports and drawings, quite a few images, shapes, and lines created, copied, and pasted.  Below is one of the errors recorded by the diagnostic data viewer:

Microsoft Excel

Description
Faulting Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Creation Time: 11/30/2023 4:37:14 PM
Problem: Stopped working
Status: Report sent

Problem signature
Problem Event Name:           OFFICE_MODULE_VERSION_MISMATCH
AppName:                      EXCEL.EXE
AppVersion:                   16.0.17029.20068

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID: 69615b7c3f7855933ee32c7e05343fa5 (2225671560615968677)

Has anyone else had issues with Connected Experiences in the past or more recently after the Nov 13th update?  Does anyone know what OFFICE_MODULE_VERSION_MISMATCH refers to?  I haven't found much of anything on this event name on the web.  Thanks for any assistance that you might offer.

We have tried a number of methods to clear the clipboard as well as use a paste routine that checks for any errors during the paste event.  We have also eliminated most of the copy/paste events.  Oddly enough, changes to the system have it working nearly completely with the exception of copying and inserting logos on a number of sheets.  They system will create 3D views with many dozens or even hundreds of shapes/lines, but adding some small file logos on a number of sheets seems to doom the entire system (except when turning off Connected Experiences).  We have tried rolling back updates that hasn't seemed to work.  The system also began working on two work account Office 365 machines but still fails on a family account of Office 365 (when Connected Experiences is turned on).

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing this Excel exception as well.  We have an 'Excel Add-In' where the user can get the spreadsheet data from an external program using DDE.  We are now seeing the OFFICE_MODULE_VERSION_MISMATCH crash.  We are troubleshooting this now.  If we figure it out, we will post back.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Oddly enough, some of the PCs that have had this issue now no longer have the problem even with Connected Experiences turned on as well as internet connectivity.  These PCs are running the same version of our software and have received no other Windows or Office updates that we can see.  It appears to be something on the Microsoft account or Cloud side.  I'm glad to see the system working as it did, but it would be nice to know what changed.  Have you tried turning off Connected Experiences?

Comment: Hey Tim, I figured out our issue too.  I had our code dynamically adding an assembly and using fuslogvw, I saw excel was calling the resolve event handler multiple times.  I had a boolean flag to only load it once but once I stubbed out the flag and let it do the load x amount of times, the crash went away.  Ugh, computers!  Take care man.